# Setting Prime face dialog properties from java script

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I don't have deep knowledge about JS or jQuery. What I am trying to achieve is I have few dialogues to show and I wanna give them common look and feel. so I am calling a js function to show each of them. I know I can set the properties at the `<p:dialog ></p:dialog>` tag. But I don't want that approach as I want a modular approach to set the properties to deal with all dialogue in my application.

**Function Definition:**

```
function editPartner(dialog){
      dialog.cfg.height = '500px';
      dialog.cfg.width = '600px';
      dialog.cfg.minHeight = '500px';
      dialog.cfg.minWidth = '600px';
      dialog.show();
}
```

**And calling it from**

```
 <p:commandButton id="editButton" oncomplete="editPartner(PF('DialogEditPartner'))" />
```

but the width and height setting is not reflecting in the dialog.

**Just a Reference**, from the Prime-face **component.js** I can see the height and 
 weight are set from cfg object.

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog = PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend({
init: function(a) {
    this._super(a);
    this.content = this.jq.children(".ui-dialog-content");
    this.titlebar = this.jq.children(".ui-dialog-titlebar");
    this.footer = this.jq.find(".ui-dialog-footer");
    this.icons = this.titlebar.children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-icon");
    this.closeIcon = this.titlebar.children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
    this.minimizeIcon = this.titlebar.children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-minimize");
    this.maximizeIcon = this.titlebar.children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-maximize");
    this.blockEvents = "focus." + this.id + " mousedown." + this.id + " mouseup." + this.id;
    this.resizeNS = "resize." + this.id;
    this.cfg.absolutePositioned = this.jq.hasClass("ui-dialog-absolute");
    this.cfg.width = this.cfg.width || "auto";
    this.cfg.height = this.cfg.height || "auto";
    this.cfg.draggable = this.cfg.draggable === false ? false : true;
    this.cfg.resizable = this.cfg.resizable === false ? false : true;
    this.cfg.minWidth = this.cfg.minWidth || 150;
    this.cfg.minHeight = this.cfg.minHeight || this.titlebar.outerHeight();
    this.cfg.position = this.cfg.position || "center";
```

Comment: So you want to be able to change the size according to some user action? If that's not your approach and you just want to set all dialog size attributes at once you should use css for that.

Comment: Yea more or less I want to make it dynamic.

Comment: The only thing I know that works is something like this var header =  document.getElementById("myDialogId");
      header.style.width = "1300px";

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I edit my answer ans show my complete code:
complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function editPartner(dialog){
     alert(dialog);

      dialog.show();

      var myDialog =  document.getElementById(dialog.id);
      myDialog.style.height = '500px';
      myDialog.style.width = "600px";
      myDialog.style.minHeight = '500px';
      myDialog.style.minWidth = '600px';

}
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello Raaj, this is for you</h1>

    <div style="height: 500px">

<p:growl id="grwl" showDetail="true" />
<p:commandButton id="editButton" value="stackoverflow problem" oncomplete="editPartner(PF('dialogForRaajVar'))" />


    <p:dialog   widgetVar="dialogForRaajVar" draggable="true" id="dialogForRaaj"
                 modal="true" showEffect="fade" showHeader="true"
                hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                <p:commandButton value="Close"
                    actionListener="#{dashboardView.addDiklat(actionevent)}"
                    update=":mainForm,grwl" oncomplete="PF('frmDiklat').hide()">
                     </p:commandButton>


                </p:dialog>
```

[image]

Comment: What is in the documentation? Can you also post thst so the difference is clear?

Comment: The call `<p:commandButton id="editButton" oncomplete="editPartner(PF('DialogEditPartner'))" />` is working for you?

Comment: Just give the widgetVar to the javascript function and get the dialog inside the funcion.  `<p:commandButton id="editButton" oncomplete="editPartner('DialogEditPartner')" />` and in your script `function editPartner(dialogVar){ var dialog = PF(dialogVar); ...`

Comment: @Ahmend Raaj. Yes it works for me. I control it with an alert. I edit my answer and post my code